# Why some commands do NOT require sudo when logged in GUI?

Tags: macos, command-line, sleep-wake, sudo, pmset

I created a user called `dummy`.

I `login` using `Terminal` into `dummy` and try to put Mac to sleep using `pmset sleepnow`. It does NOT work: `Sleep error 0xe00002c1; You must run this as root.`.

I log into `dummy` using Fast User Switching in MacOS GUI. I switch back to my main user [keeping `dummy` logged in thanks to the Fast User Switching GUI].
I `login` again to `dummy` using `Terminal` and try `pmset sleepnow`. It's working now!

1. Why is that?
2. How does it work that the command requires sudo, unless I'm logged in the GUI [then it doesn't]?
3. What are other commands that magically start working if logged in using the MacOS GUI?

EDIT: Previously I have thought it was like that because of the `dummy` being a "standard" account – I've just tested that it is the same issue for "administrator" accounts as well. Still, the questions remain: why/how does it matter, being logged in the GUI, for some commands to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently implementing the same check that would allows `dummy` to use the Sleep command in the Apple menu -- anyone who is logged into the GUI is allowed to perform certain actions.

Rather than check whether the command is coming from the GUI itself, it just checks whether the user who runs the command is also logged into the GUI. Even if their GUI is suspended due to fast user switching, it still allows the `dummy` user to execute the command.

Even if `pmset` didn't allow this, you could achieve the same thing with an AppleScript that clicks on the Sleep menu item.

The general idea is that someone who has physical access to the machine is allowed some additional privileges without having to re-authenticate or use `sudo`. Logging into the GUI indicates that you have physical access.

Other things you can do without having to re-authenticate are the Restart and Shutdown commands in the Apple menu (unless there are other users logged in, then it asks for the admin password). I don't know what the CLI equivalents are (other than the traditional Unix `shutdown` command), so I don't know if they also implement similar bypass of `sudo`.

Comment: i see. anyway, still not an answer to my questions: why [make case for just gui], how [what are the changes that allow it], what other apps [besides pmset]?

Comment: I've added to my answer.